# Date string might be one of two formats; how should I handle it?

Tags: php, date

I am alright with the basics of the php date manipulation functions, but I still get confused from time to time, partially because I don't know all of the rules firmly.

Right now I am dealing with a problem where I have a function that is going to save some data in a database.  One of the data items is a date.  Normally it is pretty easy for me to figure out how to convert it to the right format for the MySQL statement.  However in this case the string could be in one of two different formats:

```
m/d/Y
```

or

```
m/d/Y h:iA
```

I need to be able to convert either to 'Y-m-d' and I need to know WHICH of the two formats I received.  Is there a straight forward way to this?  Like some sort of:

```
if (is_format('m/d/Y', $date)){
    ...
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) would probably work with both. http://codepad.viper-7.com/flynnz

Comment: Use a regular expression to match the format, and then parse it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for each of your two formats in turn. It returns `false` on failure so you will know which call succeeded, and you get date/time validation as a bonus.

After creating the `DateTime` object use [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to turn it into your preferred representation.